# How to get with Grafana a total cross-time value of a counter-type value stored in InfluxDB?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

We are storing some counter-like measurements in InfluxDB . 
The values are monotonically grow, but can be reset from time to time. 
Reset can happen at any time (say, because of a service restart).

For instance: 
measurement: bytes_in

```
time                         value
----                         -----
2020-03-23T09:00:50.5335191Z 1000
2020-03-23T09:00:51.0335191Z 3000
2020-03-23T09:00:51.5335191Z 4500
2020-03-23T09:00:52.0335191Z 7000
2020-03-23T09:00:52.5335191Z 8000
2020-03-23T09:00:55.0335191Z 15000
2020-03-23T09:00:55.5335191Z 500
2020-03-23T09:00:56.0335191Z 1000
2020-03-23T09:00:56.5335191Z 1000
2020-03-23T09:00:57.5335191Z 3000
```

In this case, if I want the total bytes_in from 2020-03-23T09:00:50 to 2020-03-23T09:00:58, I would like to get:
(15,000-1000) + (3000 - 0)(as at 55.5335191Z it got reset and then it started from 0) = 17,000

What would be the way to achieve the above result using Grafana against InfluxDB (1.7)? 
Which functions should be used?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [NON_NEGATIVE_DIFFERENCE](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#non-negative-difference) function. 
Query may look like (add group by time if needed)

```
SELECT SUM(diffval) FROM (SELECT NON_NEGATIVE_DIFFERENCE(value) AS diffval FROM bytes_in)
```

Comment: I used non_negative_derivative (which has some issues where data is not consistent enough), but this is indeed the way to go.